# is there a way to make this more simple using sql and php

Tags: php, html, sql, database

i am generating a receipt using data from a database on php my admin and the only way i can figure out how to do it is by writing many sql statements like this:

i also need a way to be able to change the orderid while on the html page using a submit form and have the receipt update to the corresponding items

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE orderid =15';
$resultCustomer = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCustomer, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $orderid = $row[0];
    $itemid = $row[1];
    $custid = $row[2];
    $name = $row[3];
    $email = $row[4];
    $address = $row[5];
    $city = $row[6];
    $country = $row[7];
    $date = $row[8];
    $cardnum = $row[9];
    $cardtype = $row[10];
    $totalpay = $row[11];
    $iname = $row[12];
    $unitprice = $row[13];
    $cat = $row[14];
    $quantity = $row[15];
    $totalPrice = $unitprice * $quantity;
}

$sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "chilled" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer1);

$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "drinks" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer2);

$sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "foodcupboard" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer3);

$sql4 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "fresh" AND orderid = 15';    
$resultCustomer4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer4);

$sql5 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "frozen" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
$row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer5);

$sql6 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "nonfood" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer6 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql6);
$row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer6);

$sql7 = 'SELECT quantity FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "chilled" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer7 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql7);
$row7 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer7);

$sql8 = 'SELECT unitprice FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "chilled" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer8 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql8);
$row8 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer8);

$sql9 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "chilled" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer9 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql9);
$row9 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer9);

$sql10 = 'SELECT quantity FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "drinks" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer10 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql10);
$row10 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer10);

$sql11 = 'SELECT unitprice FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "drinks" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer11 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql11);
$row11 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer11);

$sql12 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "drinks" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer12 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql12);
$row12 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer12);

$sql13 = 'SELECT quantity FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "foodcupboard" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer13 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql13);
$row13 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer13);

$sql14 = 'SELECT unitprice FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "foodcupboard" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer14 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql14);
$row14 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer14);

$sql15 = 'SELECT * FROM cust NATURAL JOIN orderpay NATURAL JOIN item NATURAL JOIN tran WHERE cat = "foodcupboard" AND orderid = 15';
$resultCustomer15 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql15);
$row15 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultCustomer15);

?>
```

Please Help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. "I also need..." it is not welcome...What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

When you `SELECT *` from your join, you get all fields, so you don't need to have the subsequent duplicate queries where you only retrieve a single field.

Additionally, you can change your `WHERE` condition to filter on multiple fields. For example `WHERE orderid=15 AND cat IN ('drinks', 'chilled', 'etc').

This means you could reduce all 15 queries down to one query:

```
SELECT *
FROM cust 
    NATURAL JOIN orderpay 
    NATURAL JOIN item 
    NATURAL JOIN tran 
WHERE cat IN ("chilled", "drinks", "etc.")
    AND orderid = 15;
```

This gives you one large table result and leaves it as an exercise in looping over `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` results to retrieve all the data.

Notes:

- You're joining across quite a few tables, so you can list specific fields in your SELECT, or all fields on a given table such as `item.*`
- Be mindful of your joins, especially if you have a risk of one-to-many relationships resulting in duplicates. You can write your joins as `foo LEFT INNER JOIN table ON(foo.table = table.id)` so that your criteria is more explicit.